# How can I find processor ID in Flex builder?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I tried to find processor ID in flash builder. But I can not find it. How can I get processor ID with adobe flex builder?

Comment: You want to get it in pure As3 ?

Comment: if you're using AIR, the accepted answer here may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710880/retreive-manufacturer-information-from-device-that-air-app-is-running-on

Comment: If using Flash Player, you cant retrieve that sort of information

Comment: Dear all, I want to get machine ID or Motherboard ID or processor ID or any kind of one unique ID in my application running computer. Because of it I am going to register my application through that kind of ID.. please give me some solution..

Comment: Thank you Lee Burrows.. I will try this..

Comment: I tried this Lee, But I can not get Id. I got this error "Native Process is not supported."