# How can I get motherboard ID in flex builder?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex4.5

I am making some application using adobe flash builder. I am going to Activate it using motherboard ID as unique. I tried to find motherboard ID in flash builder. But I can not find it. How can I get motherboard ID in flex builder? Are there any way to find it..

Comment: as you are using AIR, it is possible. see accepted answer here for technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710880/retreive-manufacturer-information-from-device-that-air-app-is-running-on

Comment: Dear Lee, I tried  this code in my own. But I got error **TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.**

Comment: start a new question (including your code) if you are having trouble with it

Comment: dear lee, here is my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607594/find-motherboard-id-with-flex-builder

Answer (score 0):

I expect this to be plain impossible, as the lowest layer the Flash player can reach is Flash player's native API, which is pretty limited about accessing hardware. Also, what should your hypothetical function return if your SWF is run within a virtual machine? So, my answer is no, there is no way.

Comment: Can't I use javascript or any other way and combined it with flex?